# How can I package an extensible default Spring configuration in my framework?

Tags: spring, configuration, frameworks, jar

It is the second time that I stumble across that issue and I haven't found a good solution yet. My problem is that I want to package a framework like JAR with a default Spring context and give the user of my JAR package the possibility to use this configuration (or even an ApplicationContext implementation) to add his own bean definitions (from another config file) and to use or overwrite definitions from the default context. Does anybody know a good way to do this?

Comment: Are you willing to consider adding something to manage your modules? using spring-dm opens up some (convenient) possibilities to solving this problem, but it might be overkill for your needs..

Comment: Well I chose the Spring core modules especially because I don't need a huge application server to get a useful environment up and running. Adding the OSGI stuff would IMHO just add unnecessary complexity which I really want to avoid (originally one of the main goals of the Spring idea was to make things easier than J2EE but sometimes I unfortunately feel as if they are just getting right there).

Comment: @Mark: Could you please explain how a solution with Spring DM would look like? I'm facing quietly the same problem, but my Spring Configuration is loaded using the Manifest-Header `Spring-Context`, which AFAIK doesn't support wildcards to load multiple configuration files from e.g. Bundle-Fragments..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The people using your jar will have to import your `.xml` file in theirs, with something like this:

```
 <import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring-yourframework-init.xml" />
```

(`/META-INF/spring-yourframework-init.xml` is the path of your xml in your jar. This xml file is a regular spring configuration file)

Comment: That makes sense, but doesn't it throw an exception if someone redefines an already existing definition (I would rather want it to overwrite the existing one)?

Comment: Well, yes, but that's the good of spring's flexibility. (btw, try not defining an "id", but a "name" instead)

Comment: Thanks again, with defining a name and importing the resources from the classpath the overriding of bean definitions works without a problem. So that's exactly what I wanted :)